# Replace value with earliest date time record for dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The dataframe with monthly date is as below, and I would like to get the earliest Startdate to fill the column Startdate(including NA) for every month.

```
ID     Month            Startdate
a      2019-05-01       NA
a      2019-06-01       2019-04-01 
a      2019-07-01       2019-05-01 
b      2019-05-01       2019-03-01
b      2019-06-01       2019-04-01 
b      2019-07-01       2019-05-01
```

The expected output would be:

```
ID     Month            Startdate
a      2019-05-01       *2019-04-01*
a      2019-06-01       2019-04-01 
a      2019-07-01       *2019-04-01* 
b      2019-05-01       2019-03-01
b      2019-06-01       *2019-03-01* 
b      2019-07-01       *2019-03-01*
```

Comment: In addition to accepting one of the answers, you are also welcome to upvote all answers you find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want `startdate` to be the earliest in the record:

```
# change to datetime if not already is
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])
df['Startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Startdate'])

# update min
df['Startdate'] = df.groupby('ID').Startdate.transform('min')
```

output:

```
  ID      Month  Startdate
0  a 2019-05-01 2019-04-01
1  a 2019-06-01 2019-04-01
2  a 2019-07-01 2019-04-01
3  b 2019-05-01 2019-03-01
4  b 2019-06-01 2019-03-01
5  b 2019-07-01 2019-03-01
```